# efficient algorithm for Pythagorean Triples in java

Tags: java, algorithm, pythagorean

So I try to make a program using java.
its input is integers, the integers are considered as the sum of 3 integers a, b and c (`a^2 + b^2 = c^2`), its output is c^2. To do this, I expand the equation combine `a^2 + b^2 - c^2 = 0` and `c = sum - a - b`, get `Math.pow(sum, 2) - 2 * sum * (a + b) + 2 * a * b`. Then I get `a + b <= sum*2/3` then I substitute all the combination of a, b into the equation to see when it is zero.

Here is my code:

```
/** Pythagorean Triples
  * test case for small numbers
  * Tony
  */
import java.util.*;

public class Solution54 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


    int times = sc.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
      /* prompt the sum and get the equation:
       * Math.pow(sum, 2) - 24 * (a + b) + 2a*b = 0;
       * we consider b >= a;
       */
      double sum = sc.nextDouble();
      double ablimits = Math.floor(sum / 3 * 2); // a + b <= ablimits
      double alimits = Math.floor(ablimits / 2); // a <= alimits
      //System.out.println("another round");
      //System.out.print(alimits + " " + blimits);
      A: for (double a = 1; a <= alimits; a++) {
        B: for (double b = a; b <= sum - a; b++) {
          double result = Math.pow((sum-a-b),2)-a*a-b*b;
          //System.out.print("when a is " + a + " " + "when b is " + b + ":" + result + ";");
          if (Math.pow(sum, 2) - 2 * sum * (a + b) + 2 * a * b == 0) {
            double answer = a*a + b*b;
            int output = (int)answer;
            System.out.print(output + " ");
            break A;
          }
        }
      }

    }
  }
}
```

When I input `1 12` , it gives 25(because `a,b,c=3,4,5; c^2 = 25`), but it can't handle big inputs like `14808286` because my algorithm is not efficient enough. What is the efficient way to do this? Plz!

Comment: I don't follow some of your initial math.  Whence is this equation: `c = sum - a - b` ?

Comment: Are you saying you want to input a **single integer** named `sum` where `sum = a + b + c` and the integers `a`,`b`, and `c` are Pythagorean triples, and have the program output the square of `c`?

Comment: @PEF yes I am saying that

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen because sum = `a+b+c, so c = sum-a-b`

Comment: This seems awfully a lot like [Project Euler #9](https://projecteuler.net/problem=9) and [Project Euler #39](https://projecteuler.net/problem=39).

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I assume so, cuz I encountered this from another competitive programming question set.

Comment: this is a more appropriate question for [codereview.stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Check out https://www.whitman.edu/Documents/Academics/Mathematics/SeniorProject_LindseyWitcosky.pdf ; also there is a very fast calculator that can do what you ask at http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Pythag/pythag.html#fastCalc (select perimeter mode), it's written in JavaScript so you should be able to take a peek at the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me preface this by saying I don't have intimate knowledge of Pythagorean triples or the math behind them. I just thought this was an interesting problem, so I gave it a stab.

I believe the key to this problem is knowing what you're looking for as you scan through possible values of a. Given

```
a + b + c = sum
```

and

```
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
```

you'll find that

```
b = (sum / 2) * (1 - (a / (sum - a)))
  = (sum / 2) - ((a * sum) / (2 * (sum - a)))
```

You know that b must be a whole number. An interesting property of Pythagorean triples is that their sums are always even. That means that

```
(sum / 2) % 1 = 0
```

So all we really need to check to make sure b is valid (i.e. a whole number) is that

```
((a * sum) / (2 * (sum - a))) % 1 = 0
```

or, put more simply,

```
(a * sum) % (sum - a) = 0
```

Some other key points that simplify this problem, at least as you've stated it:

- Once you have a, b can be computed using the third equation in this answer.
- Once you have a and b, c follows easily from either of the Pythagorean triple equations.
- You only need to print c^2 as your output. Once this is done you can break.

The code ends up being pretty simple:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Get the sum from System.in.
    int sum = sc.nextInt();

    // If the given sum is odd, return immediately.
    // No Pythagorean triple will have an odd sum.
    if ((sum ^ 1) == 1) {
        return;
    }

    // Try all values of a within the expected bounds.
    int aBound = sum / 2;
    for (int a = 1; a < aBound; a++) {
        // Check whether b would be a whole number with this value of a.
        if ((a * sum) % (a - sum) == 0) {
            int b = (sum * (2 * a - sum)) / (2 * a - 2 * sum);
            int c = sum - a - b;
            System.out.println((int)Math.pow(c, 2));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

It's worth noting that because I lack deep mathematical understanding of Pythagorean triples, there's very likely some further optimization that can be done in deciding which values of a actually need to be checked. I imagine there's some mathematical criteria for that.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi it's a good method you are introducing me, there is only one thing I don't understand, how do you find out `b = (sum / 2) * (1 - (a / (sum - a)))
  = (sum / 2) - ((a * sum) / (2 * (sum - a)))`?

Comment: Hi @Tony, I got that equation by solving `a + b + c = sum` for `c`, plugging `c = sum - a - b` into `a^2 + b^2 = c^2`  and solving for `b` in terms of `a` and `sum`.